# Opening a directory in Emacsclient causes it to close when using Dired

Tags: emacs24, dired

When running `emacsclient -c -a '' ~/Directory`, emacsclient opens in Dired, but when I attempt to open a file or directory within Dired the client exits back to the terminal. Using another command to open a file works, but switching back to Dired and trying to open a file continues to close the client. Dired works fine in Emacs itself, and the emacsclient works fine if I start it by opening a file rather than a directory. The emacs deamon is still running after the client closes.

I'm using Emacs 24.5.1 on Mac El Capitan. This was a bit confusing to explain; let me know if you need some more details.

Comment: It was a problem with the Spacemacs Vinegar plugin. I removed that and it's running fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: nice. You should write up your own answer. Will save someone else some head scratching.